# tmux - how can I map new keys for the window (pane) cycle?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, hotkeys, keymap

In the tmux application, how can I map `ctrl-a`, `o` (window cycle) to `ctrl-a`, `w` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am using ctrl-a,q,#

ctrl-a I already mapped to ctrl-b

This was the three keys strokes AFTER ctrl are a,q,0 or a,q,1 or a,q,2, etc.

These keys (except 0) are right next to each other on the keyboard for maximum ease of use!

If I could just force tmux to do 1 based counting instead of 0....

Comment: set -g base-index 1 ..... [more tmux tweaks](http://mutelight.org/practical-tmux) you might like

Comment: `pane-base-index` changes the starting index for panes (`base-index` is for window indices).

Answer (score 4):

By default, <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> is bound to the *tmux* command `select-pane -t :.+`.
If you want <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to execute the same command, then do this (e.g. in your `.tmux.conf`):

```
bind-key w select-pane -t :.+
```

Note: This will override the default <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> command (`choose-window`).

`:.+` as a “target-pane” is a way of referring to the next pane in the current window of the current session. See the manpage description of “target-pane”.

---

By the way, you can inspect your current bindings with the `list-keys` command (by default, bound to <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>, or via <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>:list-keys</kbd>, or (e.g.) `tmux list-keys | less` in a shell).  You could use the output of `list-keys` to determine the original binding of  <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

From the `tmux` command line:

```
bind w rotate-window
```

or from the shell

```
tmux bind w rotate-window
```

Comment: This is useful...+1... but not quite what I wanted.  This actually switches windows around as well.  I would like to remap the ctrl-b,o option that just switches focus without switching the whole split around.

Comment: kinda like ctrl-b [arrow keys] do

Comment: Sorry, "cycle window" make me think of the command bound to C-o instead of o. Like @ChrisJohson posted, you want the 'select-pane' command.